# Magento 2: how to stop only redirect url for googlebot?

Tags: seo, redirect-url, 301-redirect, google

I have websites in .ca and .com. If someone hit .ca website from USA ip address it automatically
redirects on .com and if it hits on .com website using CANADA ip address it automatically redirects on .ca website. The problem is google not indexing any .ca website urls. It just indexing only .com URLs.

How can I enable redirection process only for real users not for google indexing?

Should I use redirect with any certain response code?

Answer (score 0):

Detect Googlebot: Instead of applying the IP-based redirection to all visitors, you should detect the user-agent of the visitor. Google's crawler, Googlebot, has a distinctive user-agent that can be identified. If the user-agent matches Googlebot, do not apply the redirection.

Implement Server-Side Logic: You can add server-side code to your Magento 2 setup that checks the user-agent of each visitor. If the user-agent is not Googlebot, then proceed with your IP-based redirection logic.

Use Canonical Tags: Ensure that each of your pages has the correct canonical tag. This helps Google understand which version of the page is preferred for indexing. For example, if a particular page has both .ca and .com versions, choose one as the canonical version.

Hreflang Tags for International Targeting: If your site is targeting users in different countries with similar content in English (for Canada and the USA), use hreflang tags. This helps Google understand that there are different regional versions of the same content, and it will index them accordingly.

Avoid Blocking Googlebot from Crawling Either Site: Make sure you are not unintentionally blocking Googlebot from crawling either of your websites through the robots.txt file or other means.

Monitor Webmaster Tools: Keep an eye on Google Search Console for both of your websites. It will provide valuable insights into how Google is crawling and indexing your sites.

Consult with an SEO Specialist: If you're not comfortable implementing these changes yourself, it might be worth consulting with an SEO specialist who has experience with international SEO and technical issues like this.

Testing: After implementing these changes, monitor your site's performance in search results to ensure that both the .ca and .com versions are being indexed properly.